# How to create a partition with gdsik without naming it?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gpt, fdisk, gdisk

I'm currently looking for alternatives to graphical programs for partitioning my hard drive. So I'm searching for an easy command line tool for it. Since my hard drive has a GPT partition table the best choice I have are the interactive `gdisk` program or its command-line equivalent `sgdisk`.

When creating a new partition, `gdisk` automatically name it. By default the partition type GUID is "Linux filesystem" (8300) and when applying this flag `gdisk` also name the partition "Linux filesystem".
I usually use Gparted and when creating an unformatted partition Gparted also apply the "Linux filesystem" partition type GUID by default but doesn't name the partition. The name column stays blank.

So is there a way with `gdisk` to create an unformatted partition without naming it ? I know `fdisk` and `sfdisk` now support GPT, so if it's impossible to do with `gdisk` is it with `fdisk` ?

Obviously I'm on a Linux machine with Debian 10.

**Edit:** Ok so apparently `sgdisk` doesn't change the name of the partition by just using the -n parameter so I remove it from the title but my question is still valid for `gdisk`.